# Webstorm: How to clone git repo into existing project folder?

Tags: version-control, phpstorm, webstorm

Webstorm 10.0.4

I create new project:

1. I create new folder "myProject"
2. I try to clone git repo to that folder

At the moment when I do: menu > VCS > Checkout from Version Controle > Git

... I see:

[image]

BUT:
I don't want to clone project into subfolder. I want to clone it to "myProject" folder root!

How can I do that (via GUI)?

Comment: this action creates a new project in specified location. Try 'D:\Projects' as parent directory and 'myProject' as directory name - does it work?

Comment: No. It shows message "folder already exists".